# ¿Cómo re-posiciono una etiqueta HTML?

Tags: html, css

Estoy probando cosas con la propiedad transform de CSS, pero me encuentro que cuando traslado un elemento en la página su posición original continúa intacta, es decir, supongamos que yo tengo un DIV, que con un botón le aplico un transform: translateX(100px), cuando yo presiono el botón el DIV se mueve 100px a la derecha sin problemas, pero cuando vuelvo a presionarlo el DIV ya no se mueve porque el translateX en teoría ya fue hecho (entiendo que es porque la posición del DIV sigue estando en su lugar original). Mi consulta puntual es: ¿cómo hago para cambiar esa posición original luego de que hago el translateX?

Gracias!

---

El elemento HTML estaría armado así:

```
<div id="carusel">
    <div id="inner-carusel">
        <div id="carusel-item1" style="height: 250px; width: 250px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="" id="right-arrow">--></a>
    <a href="" id="left-arrow"><--</a>
</div>
```

Después le metí el siguiente JS:

```
        const rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow")
        const leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow")
        const caruselItem1 = document.getElementById("carusel-item1")
        rightArrow.addEventListener("click", e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            caruselItem1.style.transform = "translateX(20vw)"
            caruselItem1.style.transition = "1s"
        })
        leftArrow.addEventListener("click", e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            caruselItem1.style.transform = "translateX(-20vw)"
            caruselItem1.style.transition = "1s"
        })
```

Comment: Amigo ayudaría bastante poner el código de lo que intentaste, en vez de describirlo con palabras

Comment: Perdón, va el código.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es simplemente **lógica**.
Todos los elementos aparecen normalmente en posición o estado `0` con respecto a Y o X. En éste caso el div `.carusel-item1` inicialmente está en posición 0. Tomando como referencia la posición 0 del div, ya se puede mover hacia X (right): 20vw. Para volverlo normal, o sea a la posición 0, simplemente se indica `transform: translate(0)` con respecto a X

**Importante**. Para usar un evento como éste, no se usa etiqueta `<a>`.

```css
 

.carusel-item1 {
 height: 250px; 
 width: 250px;
 background-color: blue;
 transform: translate(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.carusel-item1.mueve {
 transform: translate(20vw);
}
```

```html
 


  <div id="carusel"> 
   <div id="inner-carusel">
<div id="carusel-item1" class="carusel-item1"></div> 
   </div>
   
   <button id="left-arrow">Left</button>
   <button id="doble">Toggle</button>
   <button id="right-arrow">Right</button>
   
  </div>

<script>
const rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow") 
const leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow") 
const doble = document.getElementById("doble") 
const caruselItem1 = document.getElementById("carusel-item1")

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", e => {
 e.preventDefault() 
 //caruselItem1.style.transform = "translateX(20vw)"
 //caruselItem1.style.transition = "1s"
 caruselItem1.classList.add("mueve")
})

leftArrow.addEventListener("click", e => {
 e.preventDefault() 
 //caruselItem1.style.transform = "translate(0)"
 //caruselItem1.style.transition = "1s"
 caruselItem1.classList.remove("mueve")
})

doble.addEventListener("click", e => {
 e.preventDefault()
 caruselItem1.classList.toggle("mueve")
})
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Narciso. El tema sigue siendo el mismo, como la posición 0 del DIV no la puedo modificar, yo no puedo seguir corriendolo, es decir, si yo aprieto 2 veces o más el botón para correrlo a izquierda o derecha, el evento se ejecuta una sola vez.